# Changing MySQL query from username to email causes timeout

Tags: mysql, sql, connection-timeout

If I run this code checking for `userid`, I get results in 1 second

```
    SELECT userid, username, email
    FROM db_main.users
    WHERE userid NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT userid 
        FROM db_backup.user 
    );
```

If I change it to `username`, I still get results in 1 second

```
    SELECT userid, username, email
    FROM db_main.users
    WHERE username NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT username 
        FROM db_backup.user 
    );
```

However, if I change it to `email`, then the query timeouts after 30 seconds.

```
    SELECT userid, username, email
    FROM db_main.users
    WHERE email NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT email 
        FROM db_backup.user 
    );
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any indices setup on the `db_backup_.user` table?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not even sure what that means....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `NOT IN`. you can use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

```
SELECT userid, username, email
    FROM db_main.users u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT email 
        FROM db_backup.user b
       WHERE b.email = u.email
    );
```

**Note**: search for how to create index and create index on `email` in both `user` tables. Also search why should I not use `NOT IN`. it will lead to wrong result when it comes to `NULL`.